# Nexus Service is not running properly

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I am trying to run sonatype nexus-2.10.0-02-bundle on Windows 7 and Windows 2003 Server machine. But when I am running it shows following message

wrapper  | Starting the nexus service...
wrapper  | The nexus service was launched, but failed to start.
Press any key to continue . . .

When I have searched out the problem on Google I have found following resolution...

To fix this edit the property “wrapper.java.command” with the fully pathed location of a valid JVM7 in the wrapper.conf file

Which i have tried by replacing the above by following directory structure:

C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin, but still it throws the same problem...

Please help !!!

Comment: I've gotten that error for assorted problems including file permissions. I recommend putting echo statements in the wrapper script to see where the specific error is. (I assume you've already looked at the log file and it doesn't have anything because Nexus isn't getting that far)

Comment: Yes, ultimately you mean to say I have to debug the wrapper.conf. ok then lets try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have digged out many places by googling the question.. I did following solution to run it I had changed the wrapper.java.command= JAVA_HOME and then i run the wrapper with command nexus console : install and it runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think its better to check in [**NEXUS_INSTALL_DIRECTORY**]/logs/wrapper.log
 to get a more helpful error . For my case it was

```
wrapper  | Unable to execute Java command.  The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3)
wrapper  |     "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe" -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -Djava.io.tmpdir=./tmp -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol="plain ssl" -Xms128m -Xmx256m -Djava.library.path="bin/jsw/lib" -classpath "bin/jsw/lib/wrapper-3.2.3.jar;./lib/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar;./lib/jetty-client-8.1.16.v20140903.jar;./lib/jetty-continuation-8.1.16.v20140903.jar;./lib/jetty-deploy-8.1.16.v20140903.jar;./lib/jetty-http-8.1.16.v20140903.jar;./lib/jetty-io-8.1.16.v20140903.jar;./lib/jetty-jmx-8.1.16.v20140903.jar;./lib/jetty-rewrite-8.1.16.v20140903.jar;./lib/jetty-security-8.1.16.v20140903.jar;./lib/jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar;./lib/jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar;./lib/jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar;./lib/jetty-webapp-8.1.16.v20140903.jar;./lib/jetty-xml-8.1.16.v20140903.jar;./lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.6.jar;./lib/logback-access-1.1.2.jar;./lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar;./lib/logback-core-1.1.2.jar;./lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar;./lib/metrics-jetty-2.2.0.jar;./lib/metrics-logback-2.2.0.jar;./lib/nexus-bootstrap-2.12.0-01.jar;./lib/plexus-interpolation-1.16.jar;./lib/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar;./conf/" -Dwrapper.key="Km5Y5hW8ZGVToESF" -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=4092 -Dwrapper.version="3.2.3" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.service="TRUE" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.jsw.JswLauncher ./conf/jetty.xml ./conf/jetty-requestlog.xml
wrapper  | Critical error: wait for JVM process failed
wrapper  | The nexus service was launched, but failed to start.
```

Ok, its trying to access java from a wrong path.. I solved it by removing `c:\programdata\oracle\java\javapath` from my system PATH environmental variable, then retried `nexus start`

By the way, for nexus 3, the location of the log file is different

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error.
Instead of start-nexus, Run console-nexus as administrator. It prints the log and shows the exceptions. In my case conf/nexus.xml was corrupted.
Right click on that file and restored it to previous version. Now run the start-nexus bat file.The nexus service will get started successfully.